# play interactive html5 content from swiffy converted swf locally in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, flash, google-swiffy

I have an interactive swf file I want to port to android. Since swf is not officially supported on android 4.0+, I use google swiffy to convert swf to html5 which I believe it is inline svg file. I put it in Assets and sdcard, and use

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/converted.htm", null);
```

or

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_sdcard/converted.htm", null);
```

But nothing shows on screen. I also tried to read from asset file into a string and use

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", buf.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

it also fails to show anything.

I tried different avds and devices, also tried set

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON); //this one seems deprecated
```

in code. and set

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml file. I saw some posts mention to use ActionScript3 to control interactive javascript code, but I am lost for those. Is there any tutorial to accomplish this simple task?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to include the swiffy runtime.

Try to enable web access in your manifest so that the webview can get to and load it. A default conversion will have a  tag referencing the online version of this file.

Alternatively, download a local copy of runtime.js and point the  tag to that file in your SD card.